# AsymptoticIntegrate with multiple integration variables?

Tags: symbolic, asymptotics

I wanted to find the asymptotic form of

$$\int_0^1\mathrm{d}x\int_0^1\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{e}^{M(x-1/2)^2+M(y-1/2)^2}$$

for $M\rightarrow\infty$. I tried

```
AsymptoticIntegrate[Exp[M (x - 1/2)^2 + M (y - 1/2)^2], 
   {x, 0, 1}, {y,0,1}, {M, Infinity, 1}]
```

but it doesn't work. Apparently `AsymptoticIntegrate` cannot be used with multi-dimensional integrals? Is there a workaround, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your integral Can be written as product of two onedimensional integrals, for each of Thema you can apply AsmptoticIngegrate grate

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks, I know. This is just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think docs page shows clearly that it is for 1D integrals and in your example you are misusing syntax specification for 2nd item here:

```
?AsymptoticIntegrate
```

For workaround you can simply compute this, these are easy known formulas:

```
f[M_]=Integrate[Exp[M (x - 1/2)^2 + M (y - 1/2)^2], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

$$\frac{\pi  \text{erfi}\left(\frac{\sqrt{M}}{2}\right)^2}{M}$$

and then

```
Limit[f[M], M -> Infinity]
```

> Out[]= Infinity

which is quite obvious. Generally for things that you cannot really integrate, you can exchange the order of Taylor series and integration to often get nice results, for example:

```
Integrate[
  Series[Sin[y/x Tan[a x/y]], {a, 0, 5}], 
{x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, 2}]
```

$$\frac{11 a^5}{200}+\frac{2 a^3}{9}+a$$

Comment: I'd expect in future versions `AsymptoticIntegrate` be able to handle at least some simple multi-dimensional integrals like this one. Also note that I don't want the limit of `f(M)` as $M\rightarrow\infty$. But I could do `Series[f[M], {M,Infinity, 1}]` to get what I want. Thanks.